# How can I create a folder from start > run?

Tags: windows

If anyone give answer that's good to me.

Comment: this should appear at Super User, not stackoverflow =(

Comment: Asking what to type in the run box to create a directory is a real question, but it does belong on Superuser.

Comment: What happens to this question if the person that asked it doesn't register on superuser?

Answer (score 10):

Creating a directory from the command line is done with the `mkdir` or `md` command.

Since `md` is an internal command of the command interpreter and not an external program, you can't use it directly from start-> run.

What you can do is type the command

```
cmd /c md "\path\to\newdir"
```

in the command box.

You can omit the quotes if the path has no spaces in it.

(Edited: Thanks for the helpful comments)

Comment: actualy quotes should be around the path\to\newdir if it contains any spaces, otherwise you can omit them